# How does the svg zoomAndPan attribute work?

Tags: svg

[I can't find any explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute), but I've seen it used in a few examples here on stackoverflow ([ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522361/svg-resize-image-out-of-aspect-ratio)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive answer can be found in the SVG specification.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#ZoomAndPanAttribute